# Excel VBA - String padding not working

Tags: excel, vba, string-formatting

I have a VBA function that returns a lot of information about the computer it's running on. I'd like to format the output neatly, with the titles left-justified and the results all tabbed on a neat line to the right.

Here's what I thought would work, and this is the solution on many sites I've consulted:

```
AllInfo = _
    "Date/Time Opened:" & Space(33 - Len("Date/Time Opened:")) & Now() & vbCrLf & _
    "Filename:" & Space(33 - Len("Filename:")) & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name & vbCrLf & _
    "Name in Cell B2:" & Space(33 - Len("Name in Cell B2:")) & Cells(2, 2).Value & vbCrLf & _
```

But the output, in both a message box and the body of an email, is jagged. The titles are all lined up on the left, of course, but the results aren't lined up nicely.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: VBA IsNot VB.NET - the tags tell you so

Comment: Are you using a [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font)?

Comment: `Len("Date/Time Opened:" & Now())`

Comment: use `vbTab` in your strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
Sub djfsdf()
    allinfo = _
        "Date/Time Opened:" & Space(33 - Len("Date/Time Opened:")) & Now() & vbCrLf & _
        "Filename:" & Space(33 - Len("Filename:")) & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name & vbCrLf & _
        "Name in Cell B2:" & Space(33 - Len("Name in Cell B2:")) & Cells(2, 2).Value
    Cells(3, 3) = allinfo


End Sub
```

with the proper font:

[image]

Comment: You nailed it, it was a font problem. I didn't think that could be an issue in a message box, but that's incorrect. Thanks.

Comment: @buckshot  Getting a MsgBox to honor good spacing is a **WAY** cooler problem !

Answer (score 0):

You are not including the string vars in the calculation for the number of spaces to add.

```
AllInfo = _
    "Date/Time Opened:" & Space(33 - Len("Date/Time Opened:" & Now())) & Now() & vbLf & _
    "Filename:" & Space(33 - Len("Filename:" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name)) & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name & vbLf & _
    "Name in Cell B2:" & Space(33 - Len("Name in Cell B2:" & Cells(2, 2).Value)) & Cells(2, 2).Value & vbLf & _
    (etc)
```

I've also change your vbCRLF to just vbLF; that may or may not be correct.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped. It was a different problem, but vbLF does work.